# Need help to connect with rasa websocket connection in java

Tags: java, websocket, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am trying to connect with the rasa chatbot socket with my java application but not able to connect. 
I am following the below document. 
**https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#websocket-channel** 
I found the javascript example in GitHub -> https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat

If anyone has the experience of connecting socket with java client. please help.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Pritesh! Would you mind opening a thread in our forum https://forum.rasa.com/? That way we could better support you. Additionally, if you could paste some logs, that'd be helpful

Comment: Hi, @mvdb Thanks for the reply. I had already added. https://forum.rasa.com/t/need-to-connect-websocket-in-java-application/38907

Comment: thanks! We'll give you a reply there 